# Should we releaseConnection for org.apache.commons.httpclient after each call?

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm creating a HttpClient as

```
new HttpClient(new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager());
```

Should we releaseConnection for org.apache.commons.httpclient after each call? Such as below

```
final GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(uri);

try {
  mHttpClient.executeMethod(getMethod)
} catch (Exception e) {
 //
} finally {
  getMethod.releaseConnection();
}
```

From the official doc https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/performance.html it says

> HttpClient always does its best to reuse connections. Connection
> persistence is enabled by default and requires no configuration. Under
> some situations this can lead to leaked connections and therefore lost
> resources. The easiest way to disable connection persistence is to
> provide or extend a connection manager that force-closes connections
> upon release in the releaseConnection method.

It's not specifically saying which will be better. Will releaseConnection after each executeMethod degrade performance or have another cons? Or it's better always to releaseConnection after each executeMethod?

My scenario is not long-living requests.

Comment: @skomisa removed those words from my question

Comment: Update your question to clarify exactly which implementation of `HttpClient` you are referring to. The link in your question is pointing to documentation from 2008, and its [Features section](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/features.html) states _"**The Commons HttpClient project is now end of life, and is no longer being developed**. It has been replaced by the Apache HttpComponents project in its HttpClient and HttpCore modules, which offer better performance and more flexibility."_ The JDK has also had an `HTTPClient` since JDK 11, though I assume you are not referring to that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the specific scenario. The TCP three-way handshake is time-consuming, so you should try to use the same TCP connection, also known as a persistent connection or a long connection. In some scenarios, if you don't need to send any further requests based on this socket after sending one request, you can immediately close the connection.